# Server class design to make master-slave server nodes network

Tags: python, oop

I have got a design issue.
I have made a hotel booking server class that has got functions like "book_room", "cancel_reservation", "list_of_rooms", "get_user_reservations" and now I would like to make this server to be able to connect to other servers so that I could make one master server and many slaves. So when I do for example list_of_rooms I get list of rooms from both master and slaves. Or when I do "get_user_reservations" I get reservations from all the servers.

So I thought that I will make a class to hold both master and slave servers and call functions on all of them:

```
class Master(object):
    def __init__(self):
        local = HotelServer()
        self.slaves = [local]

    def add_slaves(self, hotel_server):
        self.slaves.append(hotel_server)
```

And that I would make Master class to have all the functions from server

```
def get_user_reservations(self, user):
    result = []
    for slave in self.slaves:
        result += slave.get_user_reservations(user)
    return result

def list_of_rooms(self, user):
    result = []
    for slave in self.slaves:
        result += slave.list_of_rooms(user)
    return result
```

Is it good idea?
Is there any pattern to do this kind of node-network servers?

Next thing is that most of the functions will be similiar so can I do something like

```
class Master(object):
    def __init__(self):
        local = HotelServer()
        self.slaves = [local]

        for f_name, f_content in HotelServer.__dict__.items():
            if is_function(f_name) and is_public_method(f_name):
                def function(*args):
                    result = []
                    for slave in self.slaves:
                        result += slave.f_name(*args)
                    return result

                setattr(self, f_name, function)
```

So it would fetch every method from HotelServer and made function this method on each slave?

Comment: Does each individual slave server only hold hotel data for a certain geographical region? Or to be more precious, is there some sort of data partition in place?

Comment: yes, each hotel server stores its room ie Srv 1 has got rooms 1,2,3, Srv 2 has got 4,5,6 and S3(master) has got 7,8,9. When you ask for a list in S1 you get 1,2,3, when you ask S2 you get 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9